# Как присвоить полю объекта значение по ссылке?

Tags: c#

Есть массив проинициализированных picturebox-ов. Я хочу найти расстояние между всевозможными парами picturebox-ов из этого массива. Потом отсортировать полученные значения с сохранением информации о том, для какой именно пары picturebox-ов каждое расстояние рассчитывалось. И далее менять расположение этих picturebox-ов.
Планирую реализовать это так:
Создать класс, экземпляр которого хранил бы в себе в полях пару picturebox-ов из первого массива по ссылке, поле "расстояние между двумя picturebox-ами", а также метод вычисляющий это расстояние.
Создать массив или список из таких экземпляров. Отсортировать его. И далее модифицировать свойство location полей этих объектов (т.е. что бы после этого менялось это свойство исходных picturebox-ов).
Какие сложности вижу этого подхода:

1. Я не знаю как передать в поле значение по ссылке.
2. При создании массива, нужно заранее знать какое количество будет элементов, в моём случае количество picturebox-ов может быть разным, т.е. придётся каждый раз высчитывать число пар picturebox-в.

Подскажите, возможно есть более изящное решение? Или как мне реализовать мой подход, с учётом обозначенных трудностей).

Answer (score 0):

1. Поля всегда хранят ссылку на область памяти, где лежит "значение" объекта
2. Если число элементов заранее неизвестно - используйте список `List<PictureBox>`.

Что же касается задачи:

> Планирую реализовать это так: Создать класс, экземпляр которого хранил
> бы в себе в полях пару picturebox-ов из первого массива по ссылке,
> поле "расстояние между двумя picturebox-ами", а также метод
> вычисляющий это расстояние.

Вы слишком серьезно подошли к этой проблеме. Нужно быть проще. Вам нужен метод, который посчитает расстояние между двумя объектами `PictureBox`.

- На входе метода: два объекта `PictureBox`
- Нужно вернуть: расстояние между двумя объектами `PictureBox`.

Таким образом, все что вам нужно - это один статический метод:

```
public static double GetDistanceBetween(PictureBox pictureBox1, PictureBox pictureBox2)
{
    double distance = /* Здесь ваша логика вычисления расстояния между pictureBox1 и pictureBox2 */
    return distance;
}
```

**UPD:** Не сразу внимательно прочитал вопрос.

Чтобы хранить информацию о том, для каких пар было вычислено расстояние, можно создать следующий класс:

```
public class PictureBoxDistance
{
    public double Distance { get; }
    public PictureBox PictureBox1 { get; }
    public PictureBox PictureBox2 { get; }
    
    public PictureBoxDistance(PictureBox pictureBox1, PictureBox PictureBox2)
    {
        Distance = /* Здесь ваша логика вычисления расстояния между pictureBox1 и pictureBox2 */
    }
}
```

И использовать:

```
var pictures = new List<PictureBox>() {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3 /*...*/};
var distances = new List<PictureBoxDistance>();

// Где-то в цикле по i, j, где вы перебираете всевозможные пары
var pictureBoxDistance = new PictureBoxDistance(pictures[i], pictures[j]);
distances.Add(pictureBoxDistance);

// Далее после цикла
var sortedDistances = distances.OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();

// Перебор отсортированных растояний
foreach(var distance in sortedDistances)
{
    // И тут можно получить доступ к парам PictureBox:
    //     distance.PictureBox1
    //     distance.PictureBox2
    // и к расстоянию
    //     distance.Distance
}
```

Comment: Сейчас обновлю ответ. Не совсем внимательно прочитал вопрос

Comment: По поводу предложенного Вами метода: после того как я посчитаю все расстояния, занесу их в массив, и отсортирую его, я потеряю информацию, о том, для каких объектов было посчитано каждое из расстояний. Либо придётся создать трёхмерный массив, в котором будут хранится посчитанное расстояние и индексы двух пикчебоксов. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Александр обновил ответ

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в строке    var sortedDistances = distances.OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();    должна происходить сортировка списка distances по параметру Distance? Дело в том, что этот участок кода у меня не работает. Если я пишу просто:    var sortedDistances = distances.OrderBy(p => p.Distance);    то в переменной sortedDistances находится правильно отсортированный список,но почему то мне не удаётся им заменить неотсортированный.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что код не выделил отдельным блоком, у меня mozila и сочетание ctrl+K, не выделяет код, а переносит фокус на адресную строку.

Comment: Я сделал массив: `distances_for_each[i] = new List<PictureBoxDistance>`  <br/> Далее в цикле есть код, который сортирует каждый  элемент массива <br/> `var sortdistances = distances_for_each[i].OrderBy(p => p.Distance);` <br/>
                `distances_for_each[i] = sortdistances;    </blink>();` <br/> Но в последенй строке возникает ошибка связанная с преобразованием типов.

Comment: `var sortdistances = distances_for_each[i].OrderBy(p => p.Distance).ToList();`

Comment: Забыли ToList написать